# Birth Day Reminder on Google Web App Script issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to display a birthday reminder message on Google web app where the data is stored in google sheets.

[image]

The message what I'm getting on the deployed web app is --> *It is **undefined** 's birthday today.*

The below is my script code

```
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Birthdays");
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows - 1, 2).getValues();
  for(var index in range) {
    var row = range[index];
    var name = row[0];
    var birthday = row[1];
    if(isBirthdayToday(birthday)) {
      displayReminder(name);
    }
  }
}

// Check if a person’s birthday is today
function isBirthdayToday(birthday) {
  var today = new Date();
  if((today.getDate() === birthday.getDate()) &&
      (today.getMonth() === birthday.getMonth())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
    
    console.log(today);
  }
}

// Function to display the reminder
function displayReminder(name) {
  var message = "It is " + name + " 's birthday today.";
  return message;
  console.log(displayReminder);
}
```

Html

```
<div>
<script>
      function onSuccess(quote) {
        var div = document.getElementById('Bday');
        div.innerHTML =  quote;
      }
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
          .displayReminder();
    </script>
   <em> <p id="Bday"></p></em>
</div>
```

Note: when I run the console log for function isBirthdayToday(birthday)I'm getting the following error.

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined (line 25, file "Code")*

I couldn't figure out where I went wrong. What error has occurred?

Comment: Have you ever considered just using a Calendar for all your birthdays and then just looking up your daily events in that calendar and then you’ll get all the birthdays for that day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*When you use `for (var index in range)` index isn't the literal index of the array - it's the actual element itself.*

#### Code Fix:

You can fix this by not referencing the `index` element of `range` - as `index` is *already* the element:

```js
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows - 1, 2).getValues();
for (var row in range) {
  var name = row[0];
  var birthday = row[1];
  // ...
}
```

You are also calling the wrong function from the HTML:

```html
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).displayReminder();
```

should be:

```html
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).main();
```

and from inside `main()` you also need to return the message:

```js
function main() {
  // ... code here
  if(isBirthdayToday(birthday)) {
    return displayReminder(name);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [for...in - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: I'm still getting the same undefined name along with message as "It is undefined 's birthday today."

Comment: This works for me with no issue... Are you still getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined` in the console? If you are, what is line 25?

Comment: if((today.getDate() === birthday.getDate()) &&

Comment: `getDate()` is not a method of the String type, but of the `Date` type. You need to set the cell formatting in your sheet - Highlight the range `B2:B` and select the `Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format` menu item, type `d/m` in the newly opened modal and click `Apply`. Then try running the script.

Comment: Still i'm getting the error even after changing the format, this is the sheet i'm working on. you can make copy of it to get better insight https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sx16u85-Co02juZR4d8sR85pGyCuE9CQLgWygrc1I4c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Gotcha, you're calling the wrong function from the HTML. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I did the edits as you guided, and Now I get nothing. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224685/discussion-between-rafa-guillermo-and-muhammed-aadhil).